# "shld" instruction produces weird value

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I use "shld" instruction in inline-assembly, compiled by g++ (7.3.0).
It produces some strange result.

Tried on Ubuntu and WSL.

```
   unsigned long long hi, lo;
   //some code goes here
   //...
   asm volatile (
    "shld $0x3, %1, %0;\n"
    : "=r"(hi)
    : "r"(lo)
    :
    );
   //I expect the asm produces this:
   //hi = (hi << 3) | (lo >> 61);
   //but the actual result is:
   //hi = (lo << 3) | (lo >> 61);
   //you can see the real assembly produced by gcc below.
```

I expect the result value in "hi" is

```
(hi << 3) | (lo >> 61)
```

But the actual result is

```
(lo << 3) | (lo >> 61)
```

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate for details.

It turns out that g++ translate my code into this:

```
    6e6a:       48 8b 45 a0             mov    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
    6e6e:       48 0f a4 c0 03          shld   $0x3,%rax,%rax
    6e73:       48 89 45 98             mov    %rax,-0x68(%rbp)
```

where -0x60(%rbp) is 'lo', and -0x68(%rbp) is 'hi'.

Comment: Since my code will modify the variable "hi"

Comment: Yes, it fixes the problem, but it's looks strange.

Comment: I could pass the test without any optimization options, but, when I turn on the optimizer ("-O3"), the program produces a different result and fails the test.

Comment: I don't understand too.

Comment: @rcgldr, "=r" indicates that the operand is only an output. "+r" is used to indicate an operand that is both input and output. "r" indicates an input.

Comment: @prl - thanks, that should help the OP, Tio Plato. I don't have or know about g++ compiler (I use windows and visual studio).

Comment: @rcgldr: you should probably delete those earlier comments.  "trying both the same" is the opposite of helpful, and it only happens to work because of debug-mode quirks.  (GNU C inline asm is confusing enough to enough people that removing incorrect info or suggestions is important!  There are lots of ways to make something "happen to work" that will break with different surrounding code, or with optimization enabled, or with a potential future compiler version, because you have to precisely describe the inputs/outputs/clobbers to the compiler. It doesn't parse the asm, just text substitution)

Comment: @PeterCordes - deleted them, will delete this one later.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify that `hi` is both an input and an output. Something like this:

```
asm volatile (
"shld $0x3, %1, %0;\n"
: "=r"(hi)
: "r"(lo)
, "0"(hi)
:
);
```

which produces the following assembly code:

```
mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rdx
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
shld   $0x3,%rdx,%rax
mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
```

"0" says that this operand (number 2) has to be the same as operand number 0, which seems useless, except that it makes this register both an input and an output.

Comment: Even better would be `"+r"(hi)` to indicate that the same value is both input and output.

Comment: Thanks. I also fixed my problem by converting more c++ codes into assembly codes, making "hi" only appears in input.

Comment: It only makes sense to use `"0"(var)` matching constraints when the output should go in a *different* variable, to leave the original input C variable unmodified even though you modify the register it arrived in.  As prl says, `"+r"` is what you want for this case of an actual RMW operand, much simpler to read.

Comment: @PeterCordes Please submit your own answer then.

Comment: I could, but I'm curious why you don't agree that it's better style and would be an improvement to yours.  Either way I think PRL's comment is sufficient as far as showing the simplest final result, and the English text of your answer already 100% clearly answers this question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Because I didn't know about it. I don't think it is appropriate to make that sort of substantial change to an answer that's already been voted on.

Comment: Ok, that's fair, if you see it as a substantial change.  (It's another way to express exactly the same thing to the compiler, so IMO it's not substantial, but if you weren't familiar with it before then that's a reasonable argument.)  My usual philosophy (especially for topics that I'm confident I know well, like GNU C inline asm) is that when I think of something (or have it pointed out) and *I* think it's a clear improvement to my answer, I do edit regardless of votes.  The key part of this answer though is the first line, not so much which syntax you use to accomplish it.

Comment: I do try to respect the answer people already voted on.  If editing my own highly-upvoted answer, I make sure to test and/or proofread my edits more carefully than if writing a new post.  Anyway, SO philosophy is more interesting than actually modifying this answer; it's not a big deal.  Just the general principle was what interested me more.